# Как убрать предупреждение unchecked cast в обобщённом методе?

Tags: java, generics

Вот метод:

```
public static <T extends Dao> T getDao(Class<T> cl){
    for(Dao dao : daoList)
        if (dao.getClass() == cl){
            return (T) dao;
        }
    return null;
}
```

На строку приведения типов `return (T) dao;` выскакивает предупреждение `unchecked cast`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно должен выглядеть метод, чтобы этого предупреждения не было?

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: Можете заменить `(T) dao` на `cl.cast(dao)`, тогда ворнинга не будет.

Comment: @iksuy, спасибо, работает. Может быть ещё подскажешь? В качестве параметра в этот метод передаётся `Class<T> cl`. Это может быть класс класса (`ItemDaoImpl.class`) или интерфейса (`ItemDao.class`). Если в качестве параметра передан класс интерфейса (`ItemDao.class`), а в списке `daoList` присутствует объект класса ItemDaoImpl, то проверка `dao.getClass() == cl` не работает (возвращает `false`), так как формально классы разные. Как выполнять проверку, чтобы она возвращала `true`?

Comment: Замените `if (dao.getClass() == cl)` на `if (cl.isInstance(dao))`

Comment: @iksuy, спасибо, дружище, всё работает.